# How to center an specific (x,y) point of a background image to a defined (x',y') coordinates of the CSS element that contains it?

Tags: css, background-image

I have read that in order to place a background image inside a container block in CSS you can use the **background-position** property. And you can give labels to it like, top-right-bottom-left-center or css units, mostly percents. And the way it acts is kind of like this:

background-position: 25% 25%, will place the (25%,25%) point of the background image from the top-right edge centered to the (25%,25%) point of the CSS element that contains that background.

So if I would like to center the (50% 50%) point of the background image to the (0,0) point of the container, how can I achieve it?

I know I can do it with pseudo elements (:before, :after) but is there a math calculation that can help me use the background property to make this work? Unfortunately I haven't found a property like a registry point that could allow me to place the point I would like use as my center for the background (**background-origin** despite the close meaning it is used for something completely different as I discovered).

This question is in regards to any situation but as an example I'm sharing a quick and simple snippet to make it more graphical.

By the way, I'm trying to find the most responsive solution I could. It will be much better if we can assume that I don't know the exact dimensions of the background image so that if I later change that image for another of different size, it stays centered to the same place. This means I prefer % over px.

```css
.foo {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200') no-repeat, blue
}
```

```html
 <! -- Let's supose I would like to center the (50%, 50%) of that image placeholder at the (0,0) of the container div. -- >

<div class='foo'></div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can do that with `calc` if you also specify the size of the background image. Please share a small re-producable example of your code so we can help you.

Comment: Do you have a visual example of what you want to achieve? because it sounds like just a `background-position: center center` is all you're doing.

Comment: @ChrisW. center center If I'm not wrong place the background in the center of the container. I don't want that. I want to place the center of the background in the top-left edge of the container. Thus the background will show a small visible part of it (a quarter excatly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the size of the background image (200x200), you can use half the amount of those pixel values as negative values for the background position in order to have the image's center exactly at the upper left corner of its `div` element. In your case, that would be `background-position: -100px -100px;`:

```css
.foo {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200') no-repeat, blue;
  background-position: -100px -100px;
}
```

```html
<! -- Let's supose I would like to center the (50%, 50%) of that image placeholder at the (0,0) of the container div. -- >

<div class='foo'></div>
```

Second version: If you use a regular image instead of a background-image, you can use `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` on it, and `overflow: hidden` on the parent. So that way using percentage values works.

However, in this case it becomes more complex to add content to the main div if you also need the background color for the rest of the container - You'd have to add an absolutely positioned element for that.

```css
.foo {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #bbf;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.foo>img {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.foocontent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='foo'>
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200" />
  <div class="foocontent">
    Here's some text and even some more text to demonstrate how text content could be placed above the image that serves as a background here.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it seems it cannot be done with percents. I'm not a fan of using px units on the CSS. I try to avoid them the much as I can because it makes the desgin less flexible. Once I change the background image to another one with different dimmensions, I will have to adjust my CSS to fit the goal once again.

Comment: I added another version with a different approach that allows percentage values. It depends on your particular situation concerning the content of the main div - for some situations it might be useful.

Comment: Yeah, I thought I was lossing something here cause I don't understand why there isn't a CSS property that let me define the origin from where I would like to reference the background position independetly of the offfset I want it to be from the container. Seems like 25% 25% sets the offset and the origin at the same time. I'm not sure if this is very convenient all the time. Another workaround to prevent writing your HTML is to use pseudo elements although they wiil modify the DOM anyway but keeps the HTML clean.

Answer (score 0):

The percentage unit cannot be used to offset the background image because it defines the entire image point relative to its container.
What you can do is define the size and position of the image, which uses pixel units.

Use background shorthand:

```
background: url(img) -100px -150px / 200px 300px;
```

```
body {
    background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519940640025-75fdf32010d7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1234&q=80) -100px -150px / 200px 300px no-repeat pink;
}
```